# How to know the actor completed it's execution?

Tags: java, akka

I want to know each worker actor is completed or not, from the master actor.
pls help me ...
i have a mainActor
and Worker1 Worker2 Worker3.
Here Worker1 Worker2 and Worker3 are executing parallel.
How can i identify each worker is completed from mainActor ?

Answer (score 1):

Dependency inject your master reference into your worker's constructor and let the master know whenever the work is complete.

Here is an example Worker:

```
public class CompletedJob {
  public ActorRef actorRef;
  CompletedJob(ActorRef actorRef_i) { actorRef = actorRef_i;}
}

class WorkerActor extends UntypedActor {

  private ActorRef masterRef;

  //pass masterRef into the constructor
  WorkerActor(ActorRef masterRef_i) {
    masterRef = masterRef_i;
  }

  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if(message instanceof Work) {
      Work work = (Work) message; 
      getSender().tell(longProcess(work), getSelf()); //send result to work sender
      masterRef.tell(CompletedJob(getSelf()), getSelf()); //send completion to master
    }
  }
}
```

And the accompanying example of a Master Actor's definition based on the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/routing.html):

```
class MasterActor extends UntypedActor {

  Router router;
  {
    List<Routee> routees = new ArrayList<Routee>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      ActorRef r = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(Worker.class, getSelf()));
      getContext().watch(r);
      routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(r));
    }
    router = new Router(new RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees);
  }

  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    if(message instanceof Work) {
      router.route(message, sender());
    }
    if(message instanceof CompletedJob) {
      //handle a job completed update
    }
  }      

}
```

Comment: Modified to use java, although I haven't programmed in java for several months so it may not be completely correct.  But the general idea is there...

Answer (score 0):

There are some documented patterns in akka for shutdown situations, that you can easily reuse in your case:

[Shutdown patterns](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2)

The author calls one of these patterns "Reaper", which is essentially a dedicated actor being tasked to wait for some other type of actors to die.